# installing npm package.json giving me errors

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-start

This is just an example. But for example i was creating a react project through npm and it was saying it can't locate my package.json file... Any help will be greatly appreciated.. I will also post the code of the process in creating react project. It is happening when created any type of project. I have deleted Node+Npm and re installed it and it still giving me problems.

```
Thu Sep 2818:00:09React:Node   npm start
npm ERR! path /Users/richardjimenez/school/React:Node/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/richardjimenez/school/React:Node/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 


Thu Sep 2817:51:50~   npm install --save latest-version
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/richardjimenez/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/richardjimenez/package.json'
npm WARN richardjimenez No description
npm WARN richardjimenez No repository field.
npm WARN richardjimenez No README data
npm WARN richardjimenez No license field.
```

Comment: Are you running this in the project root?

Comment: I think : is an invalid filesystem character. That may be related.

Comment: yes i am. Its happening in create-react-app and i don't have a project. I created the directory of where i want the proejct to be and when I run create-react-app <name of app> it says it that error of " Thu Sep 2819:02:04React_Node   npm start
npm ERR! path /Users/richardjimenez/school/React_Node/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/richardjimenez/school/React_Node/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent "

Answer (score 0):

You have a colon in your address which could be causing the issue.

Comment: So i thought that was the issue and it wasn't its still displaying the same error message: " Thu Sep 2819:02:04React_Node   npm start
npm ERR! path /Users/richardjimenez/school/React_Node/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/richardjimenez/school/React_Node/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent "